# Should I post my PhD Thesis on arXiv, if I intend to make a paper based on it?

Tags: publications, thesis, mathematics, paper-submission, arxiv

I am interested in posting my math Ph.D. thesis on the arXiv, but I also plan on writing a shorter paper based on some of the results in my thesis.  I plan on posting this paper on the arXiv when I am finished.

Would this be appropriate?

Comment: It's neither appropriate nor inappropriate. I've seen math theses on the arXiv. But most people don't do it. If you are going to write a shorter paper with some of the results, I think you should just post this paper, and not both the paper and the thesis. Your advisor should also be able to give you a good suggestion, since the convention might also depend on the particular subfield.

Answer (score 30):

I'll offer a counterpoint to the answers which advise against posting to arXiv.  I have posted my PhD thesis (in math) to arXiv, as well as the papers that I published from it.  I feel good about this decision and haven't had any problems, and I disagree with most of the objections that have been raised.

Here are some reasons why I think it can be advantageous to post:

- **Convenience of access**.  Sure, my PhD university does have an online thesis repository that contains mine, but it isn't so easy to find and access.  I just tried, starting from a Google search, and it took me at least five minutes to get to the PDF (the first few hits all led me to an alternate paywalled repository).  You might like to try finding my thesis in this repository for yourself, starting from scratch, and see how long it takes you.  (Post your time in comments!)  As an added handicap, you don't know off the top of your head the name of the university; and my username below is my real name, but not my full name.   Then see how long it takes you to find it on arXiv.

  Of course, the thesis is also on my professional website (well, the arXiv link is there), but we all know how those tend to move around and vanish.  It'd be worse if I had a common name.  So for the challenge, assume it isn't there.
- **Archival**.  In 300 years, will my university's repository still exist?  I guess the data will still be around somewhere, but will it be in a location that people can readily find, and in a format that they can use? (Brain implant uploads?)  The university may not exist anymore; for that matter, the country where it was located may not exist anymore.  I have quite a bit more confidence that arXiv will survive into the future.  I'm not really arrogant enough to think that people will be clamoring to read my thesis in 300 years, nor even 3, but I wrote it as a permanent document and I'd like it to be one.
- **Updates**.  In the arXiv version of my thesis, I've included an addendum correcting some errors and mentioning some additional citations that I've discovered since graduating.  I can't do that for the institutional repository version.

Some other remarks:

- My thesis has a fair amount of additional expository material that isn't in the corresponding published papers, so I think there is some added value in having it available.  This might not apply if you have a "stapler" thesis.
- I posted the thesis on arXiv some years after the papers were published (simply because I never thought of doing so until then), so there wasn't really any risk of it "overshadowing" the papers.  If you're concerned about that, you could also wait to arXiv the thesis.  In the short term, your professional web page should be a reasonably good way to find it.
- My thesis didn't get flagged as having "overlap" with the papers, which are also on arXiv, although there is a lot of overlap.  Anyway, if it had, the fact that I posted the thesis later should mean that it would be the thesis that would have been flagged, not the papers; and I think people would understand why.
- Coauthors: I agree that if your thesis contains joint work, that would be a reason to hesitate.  But I would downgrade Anonymous Mathematician's "really unfriendly" to "ask your coauthors for permission".  And make sure it is clear that the thesis contains joint work and that the coauthors are credited.  I would probably list them in the arXiv comments field, and maybe put an extra page at the start of the thesis PDF with the same info.
- The thesis is less polished than a paper: True, but I also have on arXiv my undergraduate thesis and some lecture notes which are even less polished.  I guess it's more important to me to have these writings available, in case someone finds them useful, than to reserve arXiv for only my very best work.
- arXiv has hosting costs: I don't really understand this objection, since the marginal costs of hosting one more document are surely extremely small.  But you can always [make them a donation](https://arxiv.org/help/donate) if you want to help defray those costs.  (Based on a quick back-of-the-envelope calculation, I estimate that a one-time gift of US $0.30 is sufficient to cover the storage and hosting costs in perpetuity.)

Comment: I agree with your views, and I'm probably not a typical searcher so this will probably be an outlier, but it took me about 25-30 seconds. I went to the [Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/search.php) web pages (I have their search screen bookmarked), entered your last name, clicked on the obvious correct choice, selected and copied your dissertation title, clicked "google" at the top of my internet explorer, pasted the title between quotes in the google toolbar, and the CU version was the top hit.

Comment: Ooops, I see now that what I got to was the copy you have at your homepage . . . So I must continue my quest . . . Using the back button to return to your Math. Genealogy entry, I selected and copied your institution (including the city attached to the name), then I used the forward button to return to my previous search, then entered (without quotes) what I just copied (alongside what I had previously searched for), and NOW the top hit is the version at your Ph.D. granting university.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro: :-) My algorithm was to start by Googling for `<university name> phd thesis`.  The first hit is to the university's library, a page called "Find Dissertations and Theses", and I tried searching my last name there.  But the entries there all lead to the paywalled version on ProQuest.  The open repository is hit #5 in the original Google search.

Comment: I certainly think you can post your thesis to the arxiv if you want.  In my experience, posting your thesis on your own webpage (and if you are a recent math PhD who doesn't have a webpage: that's not good!) would have most of the same advantages while avoiding the (relatively minor) disadvantages of Anonymous Mathematician's answer.  Yes, putting your thesis on the arxiv might make it easier to find 300 years later....I guess you have to decide how important to you that is.

Comment: @NateEldredge I tried your challenge out of curiosity, and I actually found the university version of your thesis very easily : it was the third Google result when searching your last name + thesis...

Comment: @ArnaudD.: Google gives different hits to different people, but for me hit #3 on that search is not the official university thesis archive; it's a copy of the file that my advisor has on his personal web page.

Comment: @NateEldredge That's actually what I found too, my bad. I still don't know where the official repository is, but I've found your arXiv profile easily, so you are right about this.

Answer (score 11):

If you are in high energy physics, INSPIRE recommends it:

"We also strongly suggest you archive your PhD thesis at arXiv.org."

Source: https://inspirehep.net/info/hep/additions?ln=en

(new link: https://help.inspirehep.net/knowledge-base/adding-material-to-inspire/)

**Edit:** INSPIRE is a website that acts as a literature database for high-energy physics. It also has useful tools for citations and cross-referencing.

Comment: Hi Adarsh I upvoted your answer but it would be better if you elaborated on what INSPIRE is to reach a wider audience

Answer (score 10):

You can certainly do this (and some people do), but I'd recommend against posting the thesis.  In my experience, it's relatively uncommon to post a thesis to the arXiv.  You do see some there, but posting theses is a much less widespread practice than posting papers.  Most theses just aren't as polished and professional as the papers they will eventually become, and I think it looks better to reserve arXiv posting for the actual papers.

On the other hand, this is a matter of taste, not a strict rule.  Here are two considerations to keep in mind:

1. If the paper is going to have coauthors, then posting the thesis could be considered really unfriendly.  Even if you clearly identify your coauthors in the appropriate chapters, it's awkward to have it appear in the arXiv under only your name.
2. The arXiv marks submissions whose text overlaps with previous postings.  If you submit a later paper based on your thesis, it will probably be identified as copying text.  Anyone who clicks on the link and investigates will understand, but casual browsers may get a negative impression.

Comment: As someone who just posted their thesis to arXiv I'm a little annoyed that I did not think of #2 beforehand.

Comment: If you are concerned about #2, add a note yourself in the comments field of the subsequent paper: "Based on chapter x of arXiv:yymm.abcde" or something similar.  This is good practice anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue in making your thesis available in the public domain if you are writing papers out of it. There is a small tinge that co authors might feel if and when  the papers do come out but most senior professors and your colleagues will find it perfectly understandable when text from the thesis appears as is in the papers as well. Having your documents in the public domain helps you and others in the field later. I prefer Research Gate (provides an independent doi for each document) and Academia.edu for easy access. You may use ArXiv.  There are also newer projects. Of course SSRN is only for papers as of now. I myself browse through original theses of authors on Proquest where available before reading/citing their later papers.

To summarise the response to your request, you should publish your thesis at arXiv online and it will neither be logistically a problem in plagiarising and content comparing engines, nor will it be any questions asked for your scientific publications at any point.

Comment: Upvoted. But uploading a paper/thesis to arXiv does not necessarily make it available under the public domain—that's a pretty technical legal term, and it is NOT equivalent to "freely available". See https://arxiv.org/help/license.

Comment: Sure, but free access to ArXiv and Repec among others is fairly certain, you just have to admit you are an academic and treat them as your own (by sharing your work, maybe..

Answer (score -5):

These days, I'd assume that most universities have an online collection of theses. There is no reason to duplicate work that is already available at the place you'd most expect it to be.

Furthermore, keep in mind that arXiv has significant hosting costs, and as such relies on donations to keep afloat. In that sense, a thesis takes the place of several potential papers.

Comment: Why do you assume this? As far as I know, many (if not most) use http://www.proquest.com/products-services/dissertations/, which is not free.

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all.  First, online thesis services have delays: even to access PhD theses at my own university, there is a year's lag.  Second, as the commenter above points out, people typically have to pay to access the thesis.  Third: "Furthermore, keep in mind that arXiv has significant hosting costs, and as such relies on donations to keep afloat. In that sense, a thesis takes the place of several potential papers." Huh?  I don't see what the first and second sentences have to do with each other.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Obviously it is personal opinion, but I don't think every single math PhD student should be encouraged to post their thesis to arXiv as that would unnecessarily bloat it. Since he is using the word "should", I think it is fair to present this point.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean: by "takes the place of", you mean "takes up space which could be used by".  I don't think the question was "Should every math PhD student be encouraged to post their thesis to the arXiv?" But I agree that the answer to that question is "No."

Comment: Personally, I *would* encourage every math PhD student to post their thesis to arXiv.  I don't share your concern as to "bloat".  I'd estimate this would increase total annual arXiv math postings by perhaps 10-15%.  And storage and bandwidth are a small fraction of the project's budget anyway.  I don't think it's realistic to worry that theses would "displace" papers, as there's no indication that arXiv would handle any added expense by refusing future submissions.